# Data undefined in component, yet in another component its exists?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am puzzled as I am able to call on a public variable in a component from a html file just fine
 - the time-line-filters component,

Yet when I try to call it from another component (engagement-filter.component), it comes back as undefined!

The working HTML:

time-line-filters.html:

```
  #productFilter
  [label]="'Filter on Engagement Types' | translate"
  [searchPlaceholder]="'Search...' | translate"
  [items]="timelineHelper.products"  THIS IS WHAT IM LOOKING AT.
  (filterUpdate)="filter($event)">
</tl-checkbox-group>
```

The javascript (time-line-filters.html):

```
import { EngagementTimeline } from './../../../utils/engagement-

export class TimelineFilterComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() timelineHelper: EngagementTimeline;
}
```

The EngagementTimeline class being used for Input:

```
export class EngagementTimeline {
    public products: EngagementProduct[] = []; BEING CALLED
    }
```

The above works, now when I try to do the same for my engagement-filter.html I get cannot read products of undefined.

```
    <tl-checkbox-group *ngIf="this.engagementService.potentialEngagements"
#productFilter
[label]="'Engagement Types' | translate"
[searchPlaceholder]="'Search...' | translate"
[items]="timelineHelper.products"  ---> Exactly the same here 
[fullscreen]="false"
(filterUpdate)="updateIndividuals($event)">
```

the JS (engagement-filter.component

```
import { EngagementTimeline } from './../../../utils/engagement-timeline';
export class EngagementFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() timelineHelper: EngagementTimeline;
}
```

Am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please create stackblitz to reproduce your issue

Comment: While passing the timelineHelper input property to engagement-filter component, the data may not have initializaed yet.

Comment: I don't understand your Input, must be @Input('items') timelineHelper or @Input() items -if you don't indicate it, the name of the variable must be equal to the parameter-